# Serial fread is too slow, MATLAB

Tags: linux, matlab

I'm using MATLAB R2017a & Linux.

```
version -java
'Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode'
```

The program below, 75% of time spends onto fread(). 
How can it be speed-up?

```
    s = serial(serial_port,'BaudRate',baud_rate,'DataBits',8,'InputBufferSize',buffer_size); 
    fopen(s);   

    size_to_read=s.BytesAvailable;
    if (size_to_read>10)
        out = fread(s,size_to_read,'uint16')
        // some code //
    end
```

Probably direct access for Java will be faster, but I dont know how.

Another solution is use this MEX https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/62545-mex-c-serial-interface
This output is 8bit digits, but I need 16 bit, can it be changed?

[UPD]
Serial speed is 4Mbit/s, I've got around 400Kb/s.
If I save the flow to txt and then read it from txt, not from serial port,
the program will be finished much more faster.
Also, it can be seen from profiler, that fread() takes many time.

`'DataBits',8` means that serial package has 10 bits, first is start bit - 0 & last is stop bit -1. After we got this two package it is formatted like single 16-bit digit in `fread()`

Comment: How much data are you reading? What is the total time? Spending 75% of the time in `fread` doesn't necessarily mean it's slow.

Comment: How does `'DataBits',8` relate to the 16 bits you need? I dont have experience with `serial`, am just curious about the discrepancy.

Comment: Increase the baud rate if possible, expect delays if not. It's difficult to do anything about I/O if you only control one end.